# How to Export Mysql table with longBLOB column and import Oracle Database table?

Tags: mysql

In My Sql i have a table

```
Select * from Dummy;
```

Column like below

```
id name salary binary_col
1    a   100   A.pdf
2    b   200   b.pdf
3    c   300   c.pdf
4    d   400   d.pdf
5    e   500   e.pdf
```

I am using **SQLyog 7.01** 
Totally i have 200 record in My Sql Database table Know i want **EXPORT** all the 200 Record  and **IMPORT ORACLE database  table**.And my **(binary_col  Datatype is longBLOB)**

Thanks

Comment: ohk...great then do...